# Trying to add an html head tag in Drupal 8, beta 2

Tags: theming, 8, meta-tags

With Drupal 8.0 beta2, `drupal_add_html_head()` [has been deprecated](https://www.drupal.org/node/2350877) in favor of `#attached`. So the old way was:

```
function MYTHEME_page_build(&$page) {
    $viewport = array(
          '#type' => 'html_tag',
          '#tag' => 'meta',
          '#attributes' => array(
            'name' => 'viewport',
            'content' => 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, minimum-scale=0.55, user-scalable=yes',
          ),
        );
        drupal_add_html_head($viewport, 'viewport');
}
```

Based on the [change notice](https://www.drupal.org/node/2160069) you now use `#attached`. So the code above is essentially the same with the last part changing to:

```
$build['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$viewport, 'viewport'];
```

This does not work though and no error messages in watchdog. I've also tried putting this in a page alter as well as swapping `$build` with `$variables` and `$output` but it still does not work. In addtion, I tried the entire thing as an array:

```
  $build['#attached']['html_head'][] = array(
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
    '#tag' => 'meta',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'name' => 'viewport',
      'content' => 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no',
    ),
  );
```

... but that did not work either. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, seems like it should be working.

**Update**

*Here is working code* which uses `hook_page_attachments_alter` which is not in D8 Beta 2 as it was just committed to dev.

```
function MYTHEME_page_attachments_alter(array &$page) {
    $viewport = array(
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'meta',
      '#attributes' => array(
        'name' => 'viewport',
        'content' => 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no',
      ),
    );
    $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$viewport, 'viewport'];
  }
```

The only issue now is that core's viewport tag does not get overwritten so I am stuck with my custom tag and core's. Not sure how to handle that one or should my tag be overwriting core's?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have $build in preprocess, so can't work like that. $build needs to be a render array that is rendered somewhere. I also don't see how this could have worked before, as this is already converted in template_preprocess_html() before your function runs.

[Add hook_page_attachments(_alter)() and deprecate hook_page_build/alter()](https://www.drupal.org/node/2350949) was just committed, and as a theme, you can implement hook_page_attachments_alter(), look for examples in the committed patch, like [common_test_page_attachments_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21tests%21modules%21common_test%21common_test.module/function/common_test_page_attachments_alter/8).

So, something like `$page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$viewport, 'viewport'];` should work in there.

Comment: Well, thanks for your help but I am still lost. I'd be curious to see if you can get this to work. I've tried hook_page_build and alter but still no joy. I even grabbed some examples from core with no luck. It doesn't seem like it should be that hard.

Comment: Update your question with your current code examples then. Surely the example I pointed to is working , as it is used for tests. So you must be doing something differently. The hook I suggested to use is hook_page_attachments_alter(), not page_build(). When implementing a hook and something is not working, the first thing to verify is always if your code is even called, by adding an exit; for example.

Comment: I've added working code which uses your suggested ```hook_page_attachments_alter```. There is one side affect that I now have two viewport tags, one from core and the one I've added from my theme so I am not sure how to deal with that.

Comment: That is what the second argument is supposed to be for, html_head elements are using that to be able to keep things unique. Looking at core, that element is added in DefaultHtmlFragementRenderer::setDefaultMetatags(). The new API there does not have a way for specify a key, which seems like a pretty serious issue. I suggest you open an issue for this. Maybe https://www.drupal.org/node/2350943 is related.

Comment: I opened a core issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2359987